# To call an external URL from salesforce

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api

I have a requirement where I need to send the Opportunity Information along with the Account fields to an External HTTP URL as JSON whenever the Opp stage is updated to Closed-won. As a response I receive an AccounId which I need to map it to the field on Account Object

I came across the below approaches:

1. Apex trigger that uses @future method with POST method(but it has limitation like 10 callouts).
2. Outbound Workflow (but not able to use SOAP since they are looking for a JSON format)
3. Custom Button on Opp that calls an Integration apex class through POST method I can send the Opp Info to External URL and receive the response.
4. Streaming API(Read not a great approach)

Can you pls suggest the best method that works for my real time push to the external URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Apex Trigger**

This can be done with @future as long as the receiver can handle a JSON object as a list and not just a single post.

If the receiving service cannot handle a JSON Object as a list then you will have to look at NON real time (batch, etc) or implement a transaction control object to process the records in "near real time" one at a time

The problem with any "near real time" option is the decision to send every change or just the current state at the time the data is sent.

**Outbound Workflow**

Not really an option UNLESS you build a custom rest service to receive the SOAP payload and then pass it on to the service. May be an option as this will work on the individual records. You will have to worry about API call limits, etc

**Custom Button on Opp**

May be a great choice as by design this will be a one for one call and can be implemented by simply redirecting to a visual force page that does the work then takes the user back to the opp. Or simply a web service method that does the callout without much control with regards to displaying a progress, status that something is happening, etc. Since it requires a user to click on a button you will not have multiple records in the same transaction and the data is only sent when processes dictate. Cons - Users forgetting to send the information. you can make up for this by implementing a batch process to "sweep" the system for records that were modified and not sent, gather them up, and send one at a time. It all depends on how critical it is to have them sent real time and the impact the possibility of the user forgetting would be

**Streaming API**

Not really possible as an external service cannot "Listen" to SF for events (AFAIK) Someone please correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation on each approach. I wanna go with Apex trigger with future method.